# Apache RewriteRule allow blank after slash or specified values

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need help with the following Apache RewriteRule

`RewriteRule ^(customers)/(active|create)/?$ /mod/customers/?type=$2 [NC,L]`

This rule works only if there's something after the `/` Eg: `http://example.com/customers/active`

It won't work if the url is `http://example.com/customers`

How can this RewriteRule be written so `http://example.com/customers` will work, as well as `http://example.com/customers/active`

`/customers` followed by nothing, or `/customers` followed by `/active` or `/create`

Comment: What about `http://example.com/customers/` or `http://example.com/customers/active/`?

Comment: The trailing `/` you mean?

Comment: Yes, is it allowed?

Comment: There are no trailing `/` in the current URLs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(customers)(?:/(active|create))?/?$
```

It uses an optional non-capturing group to allow for a URL such as `http://example.com/customers` as well as `http://example.com/customers/active`. The `active|create is still captured in group 2.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aW2QL9/1)

This regex allows for a trailing `/` on the URL e.g. `http://example.com/customers/` or `http://example.com/customers/active/`. If that is not desired, just remove the `/?` in front of the `$` i.e.

```
^(customers)(?:/(active|create))?$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aW2QL9/2)

Comment: This works well. If I need `active` to be followed by alphabets and numbers between 10 to 20 characters long, how would I add that to the above rule? `Eg:example.com/customers/active/a1dx12s5e4jklo`

Comment: @Norman perhaps https://regex101.com/r/aW2QL9/3? that allows for `active` or `active` followed by `/` and 10-20 characters. If you *must* have the characters, remove the `?` after the `(/[a-z]{10,20}` group.